# Expressing the meaning with logical opreations

Tags: logic

Note: Let $R$ stands for the rain and $G$ for go shopping. 
**1-**  If it rains in the afternoon we will go shopping.
 
Translation: $R \rightarrow G$ 
**2-**   We will go shopping only if it rains in the afternoon.
Translation: $G \rightarrow R$
Let me explain my confusions.
In the first sentence:
From the sentence, I understand that, regardless of what happened throughout the day, the fact that **it rained in the afternoon** is enough for us to go shopping. We care about neither what happened in other time intervals of the day nor if it was a mud-rain or rain mixed with snow. 
In the second sentence:
If it rained at any time of the day outside of afternoon then we can’t go shopping.
The point where I stuck is the logical expression of the second sentence. It does not make any sense to me at all.
How could modifying the logical expression from $R \rightarrow G$ to $G \rightarrow R$ would result in such a dramatic change in the meaning?

Note: Source of this question can be found here: https://people.cs.pitt.edu/~milos/courses/cs2740/HW-SOLS/hw-1-sol.pdf
Please go to the bottom of the page (the last three are related to my question.)

Comment: In the "if" case nothing preclude that we will go shopping also whitout rain: $R \to G$ is TRUE  when $R$ is FALSE and $G$ is TRUE, but in the "only if" case this cannot happen: $G \to R$ is FALSE in that case.

Comment: So do you think F→T for G→R would be true? From logical viewpoint it is obvious but our proposal does not match with its English language definition. Which is "We will go shopping only if it rains in the afternoon.". The sentence declares that if it rains you have to go shopping. But F→T (Truth value: 1) for G→R says the opposite. Although it rains you may chose not to go shopping. Woav, interesting, intriguing, mind-blowing world of logic!!!